# Google Two Factor Authentication with Asp .Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, one-time-password

Is Google Two Factor Authentication a free application that we can integrate with our asp.net MVC project?
Are there any restrictions or limitations, If we use it without purchasing?
(ex-: number of users that can use it Or number of times that can use it)
Please help I need to add this functionality to a login system.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Authenticator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator) is an implementation of the [Time-based One-Time-Password algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm), which anyone can implement.  It's not specific to Google.  In asp.net, it can be implemented using the [asp.net core identity services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-3.1).